Can someone help identify this part?
I recently bought a house in coastal Northern California built in the 1990's.  The bottom floor has a shower and this is what it looks like.  There was no trim, cover, handle, etc.  I'm surmising that it leaked and the previous owner tried to repair or replace it but was unable to.  Any idea on whether I can get a replacement trim kit with a handle, as well as if there's a cartridge to replace. What part number and make would you suggest I buy?  Thank you

This does look like a shower control. Take the picture to a local plumbing supply store. They can help you find compatible hardware.

Seems peculiar for a shower to have what appears to be a wood surface.

Looks like a Delta style ball valve.  You would unscrew the plastic top cap using a specialized spanner on those outside indents.    Hopefully that will give some clues on what to look for.
